# Terms change on Appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running on my pc a Python application and I'm storing the results on appengine Datastore to be used in my website.

The local code is:

```
def invia(utente, numero, tweet, link1, risorsa):
        params = urllib.urlencode({'utente': utente, 'numero': numero, 'tweet': tweet, 'link1': link1, 'risorsa': risorsa})
        headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain"}
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("myapp.appspot.com")
        conn.request("POST", "", params, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        print response.status, response.reason
```

It was working well, now I have accepted the new terms and the app is not working anymore and it's getting a 405 Error. How can I solve this? Is it really linked to new terms?

```
2012-12-15 03:29:58.770 / 405 49ms 0kb
000.000.00.000 - - [15/Dec/2012:03:29:58 -0800] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 124 - - ".....appspot.com" ms=50 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.000014 instance=......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't accepted any new terms recently. Normally that error is the result of making a POST request and the associated `RequestHandler` on the server not implementing the `post()` method.

If you definitely haven't changed anything, maybe you are making a high number of calls per second and App Engine is either rate limiting or flat out rejecting them, although I'd expect a 403 in that case. Try 1 req/second or setting the 'User-Agent' header to something meaningful - a lot of apps don't like unidentified automated requests.

```
headers['User-Agent'] = 'your app name'
```

Comment: Less then one request every 10 sec. I'm going to set the agent.

Comment: I have done this change, but still not working!
        headers = headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "text/plain","User-Agent":"appname"}

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after three days working, trying an thinking I got it. There was a miss typing in the webapp.WSGIApplication(), so the app was sending the "POST" to class where there wasn't any def post(). I was going crazy!

Thanks to Rhuterford, as I was thinking about his post in the night as the post method absence was the most logical solution. ockham's razor rules!